# Free group and group presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra

In this below example based on Van Dyck theorem when it say is not difficult to show that every element of $\frac{F} {N} $is of the form $b^ia^jN$ i cant understand why the elements in $\frac FN$ is this form.

Let G be the group defined by generators a,b and relations $a^4 = e$, $a^2b^{-2} = e $ and $abab^{-1} $= e. Since $Q_8$, the quaternion group of order 8, is generated by elements a,b satisfying these relations  there is an epimorphism from G to $Q_8$ so $card(G) \geq card(Q_8)$ Let F be the free group on { a,b} and N the normal subgroup generated by ${ a^4,a^2b^{-2} ,abab^{-1} }$. It is not **difficult** to show that every element of $\frac{F} {N} $is of the form $b^ia^jN$ (**why?**) with i= 0,1,2,3 and j = 0,1, hence |G| = |F/N|< 8. Therefore |G| = 8 so G is Q8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Becuse $G$ is the group
peresent by $X, R$ and
becuse we have
$abab^{-1} =e$ in G so
we have $ab=ba^{-1}$ and
we can write in
$\frac{F} {N} $ coset
$abN$ equals to coset
$ba^{-1} N$ and now if
for example $babaN$ a
coset in $\frac{F} {N}$
then we can write
$babaN=bN. abN. aN$
and now we can use the
$abN=ba^{-1} N$ and $$babaN=bNba^{-1}NaN=bbaa^{-1} N=b^2N$$
now by this equality and
becuse in G we have
$a^4=a^2b^{-2}=e$ so
$a^2=b^2, b^4=e$ then
we have $b^4\in N$ so
for the words $b^n$ if
$n\geq 4 \to b^nN= b^iNb^{4k}N=b^iN \ s.t \ i=0,1,2,3 \ \rm{and} \  bN \neq b^2N\neq b^3N $
becuse if those equale
together then relation
isnt true or $card(G) \geq 8$
and this is pradox and
for word $a$ becuse
$a^2=b^2$ if we have
a given word like
$b^ma^nb^r\cdots b^j$
we can use the equality $baN=a^{-1}bN$ and simplify $b^ma^nb^r\cdots b^jN$
to coset like $b^ta^dN$
and by the another equality
we can simplify those to
$b^ia^jN, i=0,1,2,3,j=0 1$
Note that cosets
$b^iaN, i=0,1,2,3,j=0,1$
dosent equale becuse if
One of them equal to another
one then we have paradox
with $card(G) \geq 8$
or with the relations so $card(\frac{F} {N}) =8 \to G$
is isomorph to $Q_8. \blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

First of all there's a couple typos: should be $0\le i\le3$.

All the elements of the quotient $G/N$ can *always* be written in the form $gN$ for some $g\in G$.

Now in this case $N=\langle a^4,b^2,abab^{-1}\rangle $ is the normal closure of the subgroup generated by the relators.

Because of the third relator, we can take any occurrence of $ba$, and write instead $a^{-1}b$.  Thus we can group all the occurrences of $a$ together,  and also those of $b$.  But remember,  since $a^4=b^2=e$, the powers are limited.

Since any $g\in G$ can be written as $a^ib^j$, with $i=0,1,2,3$ and $j=0,1$, in the quotient $F/N$ any element can be written $a^ib^jN$.

Thus there are at most $8$ elements in the quotient $G=F/N$. Since we have a surjection also from $G$ to $Q_8$, we have an isomorphism.

Comment: Your soulotion corect in Q8 but i can understand why when we in N we can use from word abab-1 and we can write ba=a-1b @code of silence

Comment: Oh because $abab^{-1}=e$.  Now multiply on the left by $a^{-1}$, and on the right by $b$.

Comment: In N we have word not relation so we cant use this way my idea is becuse G is peresnt by X and R then becuse we have abab-1=e in G so we have ab=ba-1 and we can write in F/N coset abN equals to coset ba-1N and now if for example babaN a coset in F/N then we can write babaN=bN. abN. aN and now we can use the abN=ba-1N and babaN=bNba-1NaN=bbaa-1N=b2N @code of silence

Comment: We can use this way.  We are quotienting by $N$.

Comment: Yes we can but my point is why and this ressone is when we have  this relations in G like ba=ab-1 then we have coset baN=ba-1N abd becuse of thise equality we have for example babaN=b^2N but when dont say this and just say becuse of relations i cannt fina why you use ralation on G in the cosets, becuse thise realation corect on G not on F/N this are corect on F/N becuse when we have ab=ba-1 in G then we have abN=ba-1N in F/N then for a coset babaN we can write babaN=bNabNaN and now we can use of that equality to simplify this to b2N @code of silence

Comment: Yes.  But in $F/N$ everything is a coset.  And if a relation holds in $G$ then it holds in $F/N$.  I could have made it more clear.

Comment: Yes, but why hold in F/N my idea is becuse of this if we have  two element in G equal then those cosets is equal in F/N and by using this we can show it hold in F/N @code of silence